# Can't delete files in trash because they don't exist on OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, trash

Something funky happened on one of my external drives and now whenever I plug it in 2 files show up in my Trash.  If I empty the Trash via Finder, nothing happens.  Ditto for the Option+Empty Trash method.

Listing them via Terminal shows them as there

```
$ sudo ls .Trashes/501
¶_|íìê<-.b?†            æâù©ìë—‡.*?§
```

But attempting to `rm` them or get any information about them shows them as not there

```
$ sudo ls -F .Trashes/501/
ls: ¶_|íìê<-.b\032†: No such file or directory
ls: æâù©ìë—‡.*\026§: No such file or directory

$ sudo rm .Trashes/501/*
rm: .Trashes/501/¶_|íìê<-.b\032†: No such file or directory
rm: .Trashes/501/æâù©ìë—‡.*\026§: No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts?  I've never seen anything like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `rm -r .Trashes/501`?

Comment: I'm leery of doing that because I don't really know what the directory is for.  Is it not special in anyway?

Comment: As it's stated in 英律功's answer, OS X will create it the next time you delete some files from the external drive via Finder. (I've done this few times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

> sudo rm -rf .Trashes

The directory will be recreated on the external by OS X as needed.

**OR**

Plug the drive into something with a different OS and zap it there.

If both of these fail, time to start checking filesystems and drive sectors...

Comment: How would one go about doing that? Both of those failed. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try running a filesystem repair.  Run Disk Utility -> select the volume in the sidebar -> First Aid tab -> Repair Disk button.

Comment: That did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

if not lucky with deleting them by the aforementioned steps, then **restore** the folders to some place on your disk e.g. your Desktop and there delete them via

`sudo rm -rf \Path\to\Folder`

this worked for me, but not inside the Trash folder itself

Answer (score -2):

if you have as live linux bootable disk..plug it on your computer. Run the linux live Cd ..and navigate to the Windows file with the .Trash-0 ..delete the file by clicking.. "Move to trash"...linux option.that will rescue you